# I get 'Task not serializable' when I try to run the John Snow spark-nlp example in Scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, sentiment-analysis, johnsnowlabs-spark-nlp

I have been trying to run the John Snow Spark-NLP example from this repository:

https://github.com/JohnSnowLabs/spark-nlp/blob/master/example/src/TrainViveknSentiment.scala

on my local machine. But it throws the `org.apache.spark.SparkException: Task not serializable` error when it arrives on `val sparkPipeline = pipeline.fit(training)` in the stack it also says `Caused by: java.io.NotSerializableException: com.johnsnowlabs.nlp.annotators.param.AnnotatorParam$SerializableFormat$`

Answer (score 0):

I might be wrong, but as far as I could research, Seq is probably a non-serializable trait. So using an Array or List instead to build the immutable variable *training* should solve the issue.

Comment: Hi, thanks so much for the answer. I have already tried to convert to List and even to import from a csv, but I still have the same issue